# $wpdb from a different WordPress database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I use the following code to get the database prefix from the current WordPress database:

```
$db_prefix = $wpdb->base_prefix;
```

But now I need to get the prefix from an external mysql database for a different WordPress site. The connection to the other database is defined in `$conn`. The code I tried to use is:

```
$db_prefix_conn = $conn->base_prefix;
```

But that doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how to write a code to find the database prefix in the other WordPress database? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by another wordpress database?? is it a different project?

Comment: @jameshwartlopez It's just an external mysql database used for a different WordPress site.

Comment: Is this other WP site hosted in the directory hierarchy of the `$wpdb`-based site?

Comment: @Rasclatt I gotta be honest, I'm not entirely sure what that means (I'm pretty new to all this). Each WordPress site is a separate installation. They have no relation to each other.

Comment: Well in order to access that particular database connection as it's been labelled `$conn`, the file that initiates it needs to be available within the scope of the calling file. Where are these two web sites in relation to each other?

Comment: @Rasclatt they're both on localhost right now. But again, they're separate installations. Ideally, I want this to work no matter where they are in relation to each other. Maybe an sql query would work better for this?

Comment: Yeah, in this instance I think if it were me, I would use a new instance of a connection with all new connection credentials.

Comment: @Rasclatt Well this is what's in `$conn` now:

`$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname)) {
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
} else {
 echo "<b>Connection to " . $dbname . " successful.</b></br>";
}`

I thought this would work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It should work, provided it's being created in site 1 to access site 2's db. If you are in site 1 and you have created the `$conn` in site 2, that won't work in the longrun.

Comment: Well, let me clarify, in the second instance, site 2 has free access to it's own connection `$conn` but site 1 doesn't because site 1 doesn't have an instance of the `$conn`

Comment: @Rasclatt `$conn` is created in site 1. I guess I'm having trouble figuring out what code I need to write to access site 2's `$wpdb` from site 1.

Comment: You just use site 2's connection credentials, that should work.

Comment: @Chris_topher can i ask why do you want to get the datbase prefix

Comment: @Chris_topher $wpdb is an object for data base connection and if you want to know $table_prefix it its located in wp-config.php file

Comment: @Rasclatt I'm assuming that should work. It makes sense. But I don't know what code I would write to do that.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez The plugin I'm making needs to know the prefix so it can use it as a variable so it will work for every user. Knowing just one specific site's prefix doesn't do me any good.

Comment: does the two site is in the same main directory?

Comment: @jameshwartlopez no, they're in separate directories. But the first site is successfully connected to the external database, so I imagine there must be some way to access the external database's `$wpdb` information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81360/discussion-between-jameshwart-lopez-and-chris-topher).

Answer (score 1):

@jack_of_all_tradestry this code  have already established the MySQL
connection in `$conn`.............

```php
mysqli_select_db($conn, 'wordpress_database_name');

// Execute a query to retrieve the database prefix
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'wpdb_prefix'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$db_prefix_conn = $row['option_value'];

echo $db_prefix_conn;
```